# Visual Studio IDE - What is this icon?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

What does this symbol mean in my Visual Studio IDE? Not the green bar, I already know that is source code. The little button icon?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The little button is a bookmark.  There is a menu that you can add on the top of the screen that allows you to move through bookmarks.  It is another way to mark where you were in a piece of code.

Comment: Thank you! Now how do I get rid of it?

Comment: On the bookmark toolbar that I mentioned, there should be a button that looks like that symbol, but with a red 'x' in the corner.  To open up the toolbar go to View > Bookmark Window.